# Slide show of jquery like the Android home page

Tags: jquery

I found the slide in [android web site](http://www.android.com/), and I want to create the gallery of my web page same to this slide show.  I tried to search some keywords in goole like `Gallery slide show for android using jquery`, `Android slide show jquery`and the other key words. But I couldn't found this tutorial.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this gallery or any tutorial the same this gallery?

Comment: @Dipaks: Click the other options in the horizontal slider.

Comment: Yes, It works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the source code on that page. It seems like they are doing their [animations](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) on [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/).

Seems like what you're asking for can be done using some [carousel plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/06/jquery-carousel.html).